# Wordpress blog in Drupal installation URL issues

Tags: wordpress, drupal, http-status-code-404

I have a standard Drupal installation with Wordpress to handle blog part.

Structure is example.com will be drupal installation
example.com/blog/ is Wordpress installation.

When i browse to a url like example.com/blog/my-wp-url it throws a 404 error which is from Drupal.

How to get rid of it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://drupal.org/node/30334 :

The trick is to modify .htaccess to ignore specific files/folders.

---

I would set your Drupal `.htaccess` to the following

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/blog/"

RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]`

And put this code right below

```
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
```